# What is the recommended way to move publishing pages from one SP Farm to another?

Tags: 2013, migration, content

We have a lot of content in our TEST farm that we need to move to PROD that's mixed in with code that is not production ready (This was a coordination failure, hindsights 20/20 and all that.)

Short of copying and pasting the content from each page manually into the PROD site, what is the best way to move the pages?

I was able to move documents and list items without issue but the publishing pages are tied to a page layout which doesn't seem to make it over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways to migrate pages, you can package into a solution then deploy the solution to your target farm.

Another way, take the full backup of a source site collection and restore site collection in target farm.

Or you can use the 3rd party tools:

A free one you can get from: http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/
Bear in mind SP2013 migration is not tested.

Also there is paid tool from ShareGate:
http://en.share-gate.com/blog/copy-sharepoint-page-layouts-and-publishing-pages